# How to size a Image to 1/3 of the width of the row in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Here's what i've got. I've tried putting the GeometryReader at different scopes but this is the best result so far.

You can the image is the correct width and height but the cell in the List is not tall enough.

```
struct AvtrCell: View
{
    var avtr: Avatar
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            NavigationLink(destination: AvtrForm(avtr: self.avtr)){
                HStack() {
                    Image(self.avtr.img)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
                        .cornerRadius(9)
                        .frame(width: g.size.width / 3)

                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("\(self.avtr.firstName()) \(self.avtr.lastName())").font(.headline)
                        Text("44hr Weekly Fasts")
                        Text("2000cal, prtn: 10g, fat: 10g, crb: 4g")
                        Text("Chest: 40, Waist: 32, Hips: 35")
                        Text("175ibs, 93% lean")
                        Text("pH: 9")
                    }
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: demo]

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid ambiguity working with GeometryReader being already inside row. So the solution is to pass needed parameter from outside.

Tested with replicated code on Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
// Just tested replicated view

struct TestImageInRow: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    AvtrCell(imageWidth: g.size.width / 3)
                    AvtrCell(imageWidth: g.size.width / 3)
                    AvtrCell(imageWidth: g.size.width / 3)
                    AvtrCell(imageWidth: g.size.width / 3)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Updated original cell
struct AvtrCell: View
{
    var imageWidth: CGFloat    // << here
    var avtr: Avatar
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: AvtrForm(avtr: self.avtr)){
            HStack() {
                Image(self.avtr.img)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
                    .cornerRadius(9)
                    .frame(width: imageWidth)   // << here 

    // ... other code
```

Comment: looks good. there must be a way to encapsulate that info in the cell. ideally the cell would require injected parameters to layout its subviews.

Comment: ideally the cell WOULDNT require injected parameters to layout its subviews.